# how to convert chrono::time_point to string without using array?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++-chrono

I posted question about converting std::chrono::time_point to string 12 days ago and solved problem. I'd like to say thanks to you.

I solved my problem using following code:

```
char no[15];
string test;

chrono::system_clock::time_point now = chrono::system_clock::now();
time_t now_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);


strftime(no, sizeof(no), "%Y%m%d%I%M%S", localtime(&now_c));

test = no;

cout << test <<endl;
```

However, I don't like this code because I don't want to use array. I want to solve my problem using memory allocation like this;

```
char* no = new char();
string test;

chrono::system_clock::time_point now = chrono::system_clock::now();
time_t now_c = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);


strftime(no, sizeof(no), "%Y%m%d%I%M%S", localtime(&now_c));

test = no;

cout << test <<endl;

delete[]no;
```

Unfortunately this code didn't work. I think there's a way to make this but I don't know how.

If someone pick my mistake or give me an advice, I would very appreciate it.

thanks,

c00012

Comment: `char* no = new char();`  allocates a single char. You probably meant `char* no = new char[15];`. I'd not recommend doing this anyway. Use a `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using that stack-based character array (as long as it's large enough to contain the result). Replacing it with one that's allocated on the free store is a waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments, your reliance on a fixed constant (15) in the original code - is fragile; your allocating memory on the heap with a constant does not make it less fragile (indeed, you wrote a bug in the extra code).

If you're allocating memory, let the standard library do it for you more safely:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    const auto now{std::chrono::system_clock::now()};
    const auto now_{std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now)};
    
    // A stream into which to write it.
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_), "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p");
    
    // Your string should now be obtainable via ss.str()
    std::cout << ss.str();
    return 0;
}
```